# Need to check if these logic answers are correct

Tags: logic

Im doing a few practice questions but it didn't come with answer sheets. Are my answers correct? Sorry if i can't put actually symbols as i'm new here and don't know how to implement them.

$$\tag{S1} A \to (B \lor C)$$

1. What can be concluded from $(S1)$, if $A$ is true?

   $B$ or $C$ is true
2. What can be concluded from $(S1)$, if $B$ is true?

   nothing
3. What is the converse of $(S1)$?

   $(B \lor C) \to A$
4. What is the contrapositive of $(S1)$? (Work the negation(s) all the way in.)

   $\neg A \to  (\neg B\land \neg C)$

Also, one last question that had an answer but I couldn't follow it:

> Determine whether or not the statements
>   $$\forall x\in D, (P(x)\lor Q(x)) $$
>   and $$ (\forall x\in D,P(x))\lor (\forall x\in D, Q(x))$$
>   are equivalent.
>   Give a convincing argument for your conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

The contrapositive should be equivalent to the original, which requires inverting the direction and negating premise and conclusion. Thus $(\neg(B\lor C))\to \neg A$, which can be transformed to $(\neg B\land \neg C)\to \neg A$.

For the remaining question, consider $D=\mathbb N$, $P(x)=$"$x$ is even", $Q(x)=$"$x$ is odd".

Comment: so the first statement says that all x's in Domain D are either even or odd and the second statement says that all x's are strictly only even or only odd?

Comment: Yes, the first one is *true*, beacuse each single number is either even or odd; so it is true for all numbers that $P(x) \lor Q(x)$. The other one is *false*, because it is not true that all numbers are even and it is not true that all numbers are odd.